# How to force the right architecture for pyq?

Tags: macos, command-line, cpu-architecture, kdb, pyq

I've [downloaded](http://kx.com/software-download.php) 32-bit version of kdb+ and installed [`q`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(programming_language_from_Kx_Systems)) as instructed:

```
unzip macosx.zip -d ~/
```

And I've installed [`pyq`](https://pyq.enlnt.com/) in the following way:

```
pip3 install --upgrade -i https://pypi.enlnt.com pyq
```

However the error when running `pyq` which I've got is:

```
$ pyq
Welcome to kdb+ 32bit edition
For support please see http://groups.google.com/d/forum/personal-kdbplus
Tutorials can be found at http://code.kx.com/wiki/Tutorials
To exit, type \\
To remove this startup msg, edit q.q
'2015.06.06T15:29:01.334 dlopen(/Users/user/q/m32/py.cpython-34m.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/user/q/m32/py.cpython-34m.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
@
"q"
"py:PYSO 2:(`py;3)"
$ lipo -info `which pyq`
Non-fat file: /usr/local/bin/pyq is architecture: x86_64
$ lipo -info ~/q/m32/py.cpython-34m.so
Non-fat file: ~/q/m32/py.cpython-34m.so is architecture: x86_64
```

So basically `py.cpython-34m.so` has x86_64 architecture (which is fine), but it seems to fail when running under kdb+ 32bit edition. I could install kdb+ 64bit, however only 32bit edition is free.

I've tried to run it as:

```
$ arch -i386 pyq
```

to force 32-bit architecture (the same with `arch -x86_64 pyq`), but different error appears:

> arch: posix_spawnp: pyq: Bad CPU type in executable

My architecture is `x86_64` as per:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Pro-2.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookPro11,3 Darwin
```

How do I install compatible version of `pyq` or force it to run under the right architecture?

Comment: Suggest you tell the original authors about it; should just work with 32bit kdb+ according to their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend using universal libraries on Mac OSX.  In our testing, PyQ works well with the pre-installed system Python

```
$ lipo -info /usr/bin/python
Architectures in the fat file: /usr/bin/python are: x86_64 i386
```

and Python installed by "brew" using the --universal option.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from source using gcc 32-bit libs?

See: [INSTALL.md](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/pyq/install/).

I think you may need to run this inside 32-bit Python.